# Docker exec command gets failed?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, exec, docker-machine, linux-containers

I am new to Docker Concept , I just started today  playing with it .
And I found out the **exec** command  whose job is to  run a new command in a running container.

I am inside `~/linux-tweet-app` directory  which contains `index-original.html` and `index.html` files.
My container is running :

```
 docker container run \
 --detach \
 --publish 80:80 \
 --name linux_tweet_app \
 --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/usr/share/nginx/html \
 $DOCKERID/linux_tweet_app:1.0
```

My task is to copy **index-original.html** content to **index.html** . 
As i am using bind mount on docker host so, this works:

```
 cp index-new.html index.html
```

and the changes got reflected ,

But while doing so with ***exec***:

```
docker exec -it linux_tweet_app cp index-original.html index.html
```

I got the following error :
[image]

I am not able to understand what is happening? Any help would be appreciated to this newcomer

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you need to use full path inside container, so this should work:

```
docker exec -it linux_tweet_app cp /usr/share/nginx/html/index-original.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

You may also specify WORKDIR in Dockerfile and set it to /usr/share/nginx/html